# Resource keeps creating another designer file after adding new item

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

Everytime i add some string in my resource file, when i save it creates another designer file
[image]

how to stop this?

Comment: Hi, which version of Visual Studio are you using, and what are your configurations when creating the webform? I cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: VS 2019, 16.11.5. Not creating a web form, just adding a new string to the resource file.

Comment: Have you tried using Visual Studio Installer to repair Visual Studio? In addition, why is it not applicable to VS 2022? There are no issues when I use it.

Comment: Are you using Git?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT tfs